# Maintenance mode for the Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

Is there any way to enable the display of a static HTML page to explain that a site is in maintenance during times such as when the Play Framework is compiling new code?

I can see how we could manually create a maintenance page for things such as while a long database or file change is undergoing (during which the application may be in an inconsistent state), but is there any built-in approach for the Play Framework?

I know that some other major server software like Nginx have a way to display a static resource here. Since the Play Framework is also the server software, does it have an equivalent?

Comment: "compiling new code" makes it sound like you're running your server in dev mode, Play will never recompile anything in production—it doesn't do hot reloading in prod.

Comment: Re-phrase your question. "You want the play server to display a page when the play server is unavailable." This should not be handled by the app itself. It should be done by an reverse proxy for example.

Comment: @Ryan, it's indeed in productive mode, after restarting the server following code changes (eg, a `git pull`). I'm not concerned about the time needed to restart Play, but the compilation process can take a bit of time during which Play could readily serve a static page.

Comment: If that's what you want then you need a reverse proxy as @i.am.michiel said.  Play won't be responding to any requests at all during that time.

Comment: @i.am.michiel, I suppose there might be two different possibilities here. One is to display an alternative page while I cannot display the normal page (eg, some database tables must be generated and we can't display the regular content until this is done). acjay's answer seems to work for this. The other possibility is displaying an alternative page during the compilation process as I described in my comment to Ryan. If a reverse proxy is the solution to this, could you elaborate as to how I would set that up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure. Your best bet is to use [request interceptors](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaInterceptors). This is using a request filter, lightly adapted from those docs:

```
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.mvc._

object MaintenanceModeFilter extends Filter {
  def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(request: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    if (/* check for trigger */) {
      Logger.info("Sending maintenance mode response")
      Ok(/* your maintenance page */)
    } else {
      next(request)
    }
  }
}

object Global extends WithFilters(AccessLoggingFilter)
```

You could probably make it work with `onRouteRequest`, also mentioned in those docs, if you prefer.